# Multiple JQuery .getJSON callbacks do not fire

Tags: json, jquery

I am attempting to run the following code snippet:

```
var myVar1 = $.getJSON('myurl', function(json) {
    console.log("debug1", json);
});
var myVar2 = $.getJSON('myurl2', function(json2) {
    console.log("debug2", json2);
});
```

And I never see the "debug2" entry appear in my console log. When I check the status of `myVar2` after the requests have completed, I see it populated with the correct data. When I append a `.complete()` statement at the end of the of the second `.getJSON()` request, the `.complete()` function will fire correctly.

Using jQuery 1.7.2 and lastest stable of google chrome. Why will the second callback function not fire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
var myVar2 = $.getJSON('myurl2').success(function(){
    console.log("debug2 - success");
}).error(function(){
    console.log("debug2 - error");
});
```

You will probably see the error message and not success. I would guess that 'myurl2' does not exist though it could be that it does exist but the script makes an HTTP response with an error heading. I think a JSON decode failure will also fire the error callback.

Comment: Thanks Beetroot! You are correct, the second URL is firing some sort of error. I'm not sure why, I've replaced everything with the first URL and it returns a `.success()`. Do are you aware of methods I can use to see what error it is throwing?

I've created the function: `.error(function(data) { console.log("error" , data); })` and in the data object I can see the responseText that I want, but I am not sure why it is returning an error. Any ideas?

Comment: Upon futher inspection (and using the error function `.error(function(data, data2, data3) { console.log("error" , data, data2, data3); })` I have found there is a parse error! one of the values returned is a double with NaN not enclosed in quotes and throwing a parse error. This is a new problem to solve :) thanks for your help!

Comment: Ian, fyi the `.error()` callback's arguments (and many other things) are explained in jQuery's [ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).